# jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'admin.forms.MyForm object' has no attribute 'hidden_tag'

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, flask-admin

So I have a `wtforms_alchemy` *form* class in my **main.py** (this uses `flask_admin`). This *form* class is retrieving *database* class from `sqlachemy`. When I try to load the form in main.py, this error throws up.

**main.py**

```
class MyFormView(BaseView):

    @expose('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def my_form(self):
        form = MyForm()

        if request.method == "POST":
            return "congrats!"


        return self.render('admin/my_form.html', form=form)

 admin.add_view(MyFormView(name='My Form', endpoint='/form-endpoint'))
```

**form.py**

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyDatabaseUser

# The MyDatabaseUser is the database class with SQLAlchemy
# sample of what my database looks like
# class MyDatabaseUser(db.Model):
#     id = db.Column(UUIDType(binary=False), default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True)
#     date = db.Column(db.Date)
#     amount = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

**admin/my_form.html**

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}

{% block body %}
{{ super() }}
<div class="container">
    <form method="POST" action="/form-endpoint">
        <dl>
        {{ wtf.quick_form(form)}}

         <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit Me!">
         </dl>
     </form>
</div>
{% endblock body %}
```

**Error shown**

> jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'admin.forms.MyForm
>   object' has no attribute 'hidden_tag'

Anyone has any idea on where's the issue?

Comment: This issue is discussed on the wtforms-alchemy Github pgaes: ['csrf protection in wtforms-alchemy'](https://github.com/kvesteri/wtforms-alchemy/issues/74).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @pjcunningham I will post the answer here. In your `wtforms_alchemy` just need to:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm

class MyForm(ModelForm, FlaskForm):
    class Meta:
        #model = whateverYourSQLAlchemy
```